# How to use extension to insert before an xsd:sequence?

Tags: xml, xsd

In all examples about extending a sequence, all new elements are appened at the end.
See `personinfo` and `fullpersoninfo` at :
http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex.asp

How to define a new sequence by extension to insert new elements before ? Example (the 2nd part is wrong; how to correct it ?) :

```
<xs:complexType name="address">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="fullpersoninfo">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:extension base="address"/>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

The aim is to validate some elements where `city` and `country` are at the end of many sequences.

Example :

```
<Employee>
  <name>A.Miller</name>
  <city>Madrid</city>
  <country>Spain</country>
</Employee>
<Flight>
  <airport>CDG</airport>
  <city>Paris</city>
  <country>France</country>
</Flight>
```

Comment: When a complexType is extended, the new elements are added after to the base elements as sequence. So it's impossible.

Comment: Agree with @Xstian that `xs:extension` can't be used in that way.  See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29130733/290085) for references and an alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Xstian mentioned in the comments, `xs:extension` doesn't work that way.  Details follow, along with an alternative suggestion...

### XSD 1.0

Extension cannot insert new elements ***before*** a sequence; they must be appended ***after*** the sequence.  According to the XSD 1.0 spec, [XML Schema Part 1: Structures Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Complex_Type_Definition):

> A complex type which extends another does so by having additional
>   content model particles at the end of the other definition's content
>   model, or by having additional attribute declarations, or both.
>
> - **Note**: This specification allows only appending, and not other kinds    of extensions. This decision simplifies application
>     processing    required to cast instances from derived to base type.
>     Future versions    may allow more kinds of extension, requiring more
>     complex    transformations to effect casting.

### XSD 1.1

Some special cases are supported but still not ones that would allow insertions before a sequence as you seek.  According to the XSD 1.1 spec, [W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD) 1.1 Part 1: Structures](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#Complex_Type_Definition):

> A complex type which extends another does so by having additional
>   content model particles at the end of the other definition's content
>   model, or by having additional attribute declarations, or both.
>
> - **Note**: For the most part, this specification allows only appending,    and not other kinds of extensions. This decision
>     simplifies    application processing required to cast instances from
>     the derived    type to the base type. One special case allows the
>     extension of    all-groups in ways that do not guarantee that the new
>     material occurs    only at the end of the content. Another special
>     case is extension via    Open Contents in ***interleave*** mode.

### Alternative Suggestion: Groups

Instead of `xs:extension` you could use `xs:group` to factor out the common element definitions and insert new elements before them.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Employee>
    <name>A.Miller</name>
    <city>Madrid</city>
    <country>Spain</country>
  </Employee>
  <Flight>
    <airport>CDG</airport>
    <city>Paris</city>
    <country>France</country>
  </Flight>
</root>
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:group name="AddressGroup">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>

  <xs:complexType name="EmployeeType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:group ref="AddressGroup"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="FlightType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="airport" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:group ref="AddressGroup"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Employee" type="EmployeeType"/>
        <xs:element name="Flight" type="FlightType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I'm totally agreed :)