# XSD: How to use an element of a type derived from an abstract type correctly?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have the following schema containing the definition of an abstract list type and the definition of a concrete `List` type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="BaseListContent" abstract="true" />

  <xs:complexType name="BaseList" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element name="content" type="BaseListContent" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ListContent">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="BaseListContent">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="10" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="List">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="BaseList">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="content" type="ListContent" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="list" type="List" />

</xs:schema>
```

Now I'm trying to validate the following XML document against the schema:

```
<list>
  <id>1</id>
  <content>
    <id>1</id>
    <id>2</id>
  </content>
</list>
```

But *xmllint* tells me that the document is not valid:

```
> xmllint --noout --schema ~/test.xsd ~/test.xml
test.xml:1: element list: Schemas validity error : Element 'list': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( content ).
test.xml fails to validate
```

What is the problem here, as there clearly is a child element `content`?

Update: a more recent version of *xmllint* (using libxml version 20904) shows me an error in the schema.

```
$ xmllint --noout --schema test.xsd test.xml
test.xml:3: element content: Schemas validity error : Element 'content': The type definition is abstract.
test.xml:1: element list: Schemas validity error : Element 'list': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( content ).
test.xml fails to validate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSD itself has a problem even prior to validation of your XML document:

> [Error] test.xsd:23:31: cos-element-consistent: Error for type `List`.
>   Multiple elements with name `content`, with different types, appear in
>   the model group.

The content model for `List` is an extension of `BaseList` and so can only ***add*** elements, not modify existing elements.  Also, ***same-named but different-typed elements cannot share a parent***:

**See also:**

- [How to use extension to insert before an xsd:sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29118780/290085)
- [XSD element substitution group example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39868769/290085)

Comment: Thanks. I tried with a more recent version of *xmllint* and now it indicates an error in the schema. I guess there is no easy way to get a valid schema for this?

Comment: Clearly you could write an XSD that'll validate that XML if you rework (or forgo entirely) its inheritance structure.

Comment: Sure, but the point of the my schema was to get a base list and content type, and then easily be able to create a bunch of concrete list types having different content. Oh well... back to the drawing board then.

Comment: I added a couple of links that may help as you explore alternatives.

Comment: Thanks again. Groups look like they could be of help to me in this case.